# Dropdown menu wont close

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #0F8C8C;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

body {
 line-height: 1.75em;
 background: url("../images/obg.png");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

body,input {
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

strong {
 color: #000000;
}

br.clearfix {
 clear: both;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
 font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 2.25em;
}

h2,h3,h4 {
 color: #2C2B2B;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

h3 {
 font-size: 1.75em;
}

h4 {
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

img.alignleft {
 margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
 float: left;
}

img.aligntop {
 margin: 5px 0 20px 0;
}

img.pic {
 padding: 5px;
 border: solid 1px #D4D4D4;
}

p {
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

ul {
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

ul h4 {
 margin-bottom: 0.35em;
}

.box {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.date {
 background: #6E6E6E;
 padding: 5px 6px 5px 6px;
 margin: 0 6px 0 0;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

#content {
 width: 665px;
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}

#content-box1 {
 width: 320px;
 float: left;
}

#content-box2 {
 margin: 0 0 0 345px;
 width: 320px;
}

#footer {
 margin: 40px 0 120px 0;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}

#footer a {
 color: #000000;
}

#header {
 height: 75px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 45px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 888px;
 overflow: hidden;
}


li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
}

.dropdown-content {
 background: url('../images/nav.png');
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border: thin solid #000000;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
}

.show {display:block;}


#menu {
 padding: 0 45px 0 45px;
 position: relative;
    background: url('../images/nav.png');
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 width: 890px;
 border-top: 1px solid #000000;
 }

#menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: large;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

#menu ul {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
 display: table-cell;
 background-position: 0 -118px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 49px;
 width: 122px;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 1px;
 text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li.first {
 padding-left: 0;
}



#page {
 background: url('../images/lgcont.jpg');
 padding: 45px 45px 15px 45px;
 position: relative;
 width: 890px;
 margin: 0;
}

#page .section-list {
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 0;
}

#page .section-list li {
 clear: both;
 padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

#page ul {
 list-style: none;
}

#page ul li {
 border-top: solid 1px #D4D4D4;
 padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

#page ul li.first {
 padding-top: 0;
 border-top: 0;
}

#page-bottom {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 background: #000000 url('../images/banner2.jpg') no-repeat left top;
 width: 890px;
 height: 200px;
 padding: 45px 45px 0 45px;
 color: #000000;
}

#page-bottom a {
 color: #F5F5F5;
}

#page-bottom h2, #page-bottom h3, #page-bottom h4 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

#page-bottom ul {
 list-style: none;
}

#page-bottom ul li {
 border-top: solid 1px #8F8F8F;
 padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

#page-bottom ul li.first {
 padding-top: 0;
 border-top: 0;
}

#page-bottom-content {
 width: 665px;
 float: left;
 clear: right;
}

#page-bottom-sidebar {
 width: 200px;
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 float: right;
}

#search input.form-submit {
 margin-left: 1em;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #2FACAC;
 border: 0;
}

#search input.form-text {
 border: solid 1px #8F8F8F;
 padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 0 0 690px;
}

#splash {
 background: url('../images/lgcont.jpg');
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 height: 374px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 45px 45px 10px 45px;
 width: 890px;
}

#splash .pic {
 padding: 9px;
}

#wrapper {
 background: url('../images/lgcont.jpg');
    border: solid 1px #000000;
 background-size:cover;
 position: relative;
 width: 980px;
 margin: 75px auto 0 auto;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Mimars Energy Sdn Berhad - Your Best Partner in Business</title>
<link rel="icon" href="images/favImage.png" type="image/png"/>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<style type="text/css">
.style6 {
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.style7 {
 text-align: center;
}
.style8 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: xx-large;
}
.style9 {
 text-align: left;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.style10 {
 text-align: left;
}
.style13 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size: xx-large;
}
.style15 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size: x-large;
}
.style17 {
 font-size: large;
}
.style18 {
 text-align: left;
 font-size: large;
}
.style19 {
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size: large;
}
.style20 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: large;
}
.style21 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size: large;
}
.style22 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: small;
}
.style23 {
 font-size: x-large;
}
</style>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header" style="background-image: url('images/logo.jpg'); width: 890px">
  <img height="128" src="images/logo%20spin.gif" style="position: relative; left: 12px; top: -37px;" width="128" /></div>
 <div id="menu">
  <ul>
   <li class="first current_page_item"><span class="style6"><a href="index.html">
   Home</a></li>
   
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction1()">Profile</a>
       <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown1">
         <a href="profile.html">Mission & Vision</a>
         <a href="license.html">License</a>
       </div>
     </li> 
         
     <li><a href="project.html">Project</a></li>
   <li><a href="suppliers.html">Suppliers</a></li>
   
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction2()">Partners</a>
       <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown2">
         <a href="internationalpartners.html">International</a>
         <a href="localpartners.html">Local</a>
       </div>
     </li> 
       
     <li class="last"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br class="clearfix" />
 </div>
 <div id="page" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 1549px;">
  <table style="width: 100%">
   <tr>
    <td class="style13">
    <strong>WELCOME TO MIMARS ENERGY</strong></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
  <span class="style6"><br />
  <table style="width: 100%">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="style7" style="height: 269px"><span class="style6">
  
  <iframe src="slideshow.html" frameborder="0" style="border: thin solid #000000; width: 80%; height: 354px; left: 2px; top: -2px; overflow: hidden;" allowfullscreen id="I1" class="style8" name="I1"></iframe>
    </span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="style13" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="style21" colspan="4">We envision ourselves to become 
    the key provider of ICT solutions, manpower supply &amp; other 
    supplies and services to organizations locally and beyond.</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="style15" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="style15" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><span class="style13"><strong><br />
    <span class="style23">Services</span><br />
    </strong></span>
    <br class="style7" />
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px" class="style7"><span class="style6"></span>
    <img alt="network" height="103" src="images/network.png" style="position: relative; left: 12px; top: -3px;" width="102" /></td>
    <td style="width: 4584px" class="style10"><span class="style17">Network</span><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </strong></td>
    <td style="width: 4035px" class="style7"><span class="style6"></span>
    <img alt="manpower" height="107" src="images/manpower.png" style="position: relative; left: 22px; top: 1px;" width="105" /></td>
    <td style="width: 4634px" class="style17">Manpower</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px">
    <img alt="software" height="105" src="images/software.png" style="position: relative; left: 66px; top: 2px;" width="103" /><br class="style7" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 4584px" class="style18">Software</td>
    <td style="width: 4035px" class="style7"><span class="style6"></span>
    <img alt="safety" height="107" src="images/safety.png" style="position: relative; left: 24px; top: -2px;" width="104" /></td>
    <td style="width: 4634px" class="style17">Safety</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px">
    <img alt="videoconference" height="101" src="images/video.png" style="position: relative; left: 67px; top: 3px;" width="102" /></td>
    <td style="width: 4584px" class="style10"><span class="style17">Video Conferencing &amp; 
    AV/</span><span class="style19">Solutions</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><span class="style6"><strong>
    <span class="style13"><br />
        <span class="style23">News &amp; Events</span><br />
    </span>
    </strong></span>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px">
    <img alt="computer" height="83" src="images/Computer.png" style="position: relative; left: 79px; top: 3px;" width="83" /></td>
    <td class="style9" colspan="3"><span class="style20">Supply &amp; 
    Maintenance Computers for </span><strong><span class="style20">JX 
    Nippon Oil &amp; Energy Corporation (Miri Branch)</span></strong></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px">
    <img height="56" src="images/flircam.jpg" style="position: relative; left: 83px; top: 1px;" width="83" /></td>
    <td colspan="3"><span class="style7"><span class="style17">Installing 
    FLIR camera at </span> 
    </span> <span class="style20"> <strong>PETRONAS Miri Crude Oil Terminal </strong></span>
    <span class="style22">(Click <a href="project3page.html">here</a> to view)</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px">
    <img height="83" src="images/cardaccess.png" style="position: relative; left: 82px; top: 0px;" width="83" /></td>
    <td colspan="3"><span class="style20">Security Access Management System at </span> 
    <span class="style20"> <strong>
    PETRONAS 
    FLNG Building </strong></span>
    <span class="style22">(Click <a href="project2page.html">here</a> to view)</span></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <span class="style6"></span>
 </div>
 <div id="page-bottom" style="left: 0px; top: 0px">
 </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 Copyright &copy; 2016 <a href="index.html">www.mimars.com.my</a> All rights reserved.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have 2 dropdown menus. When I click on the 1st menu it opens as expected. Then, when I click on the 2nd dropdown, the 1st dropdown won't close. How do I fix this? Is my script the problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you fix your question. Cause if I click run on codesnippet. I can't see any dropdown fields.

Comment: hello i already edit the code

Comment: I don't see a drop-down in the sample code :/ - please fix the question into a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Things I changed:

1. One global `CloseAll()` function
2. One toggle function (`myFunction`)
3. Dropdown target as argument of the toggle function `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction('myDropdown1')">Profile</a>`

```js
function myFunction(target) {  
    var dropdown = document.getElementById(target);
    var isOpen =  dropdown.classList.contains('show')
    closeAll();   
    if(!isOpen)
      dropdown.classList.toggle("show");
}

function closeAll() {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
 }

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
     closeAll();
  }
}
```

**Working demo**

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #0F8C8C;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

body {
 line-height: 1.75em;
 background: url("../images/obg.png");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

body,input {
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

strong {
 color: #000000;
}

br.clearfix {
 clear: both;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
 font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 2.25em;
}

h2,h3,h4 {
 color: #2C2B2B;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

h3 {
 font-size: 1.75em;
}

h4 {
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

img.alignleft {
 margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
 float: left;
}

img.aligntop {
 margin: 5px 0 20px 0;
}

img.pic {
 padding: 5px;
 border: solid 1px #D4D4D4;
}

p {
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

ul {
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

ul h4 {
 margin-bottom: 0.35em;
}

.box {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.date {
 background: #6E6E6E;
 padding: 5px 6px 5px 6px;
 margin: 0 6px 0 0;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

#content {
 width: 665px;
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}

#content-box1 {
 width: 320px;
 float: left;
}

#content-box2 {
 margin: 0 0 0 345px;
 width: 320px;
}

#footer {
 margin: 40px 0 120px 0;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}

#footer a {
 color: #000000;
}

#header {
 height: 75px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 45px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 888px;
 overflow: hidden;
}


li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
}

.dropdown-content {
 background: url('../images/nav.png');
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border: thin solid #000000;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
}

.show {display:block;}


#menu {
 padding: 0 45px 0 45px;
 position: relative;
    background: url('../images/nav.png');
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 width: 890px;
 border-top: 1px solid #000000;
 }

#menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: large;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

#menu ul {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
 display: table-cell;
 background-position: 0 -118px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 49px;
 width: 122px;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 1px;
 text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li.first {
 padding-left: 0;
}



#page {
 background: url('../images/lgcont.jpg');
 padding: 45px 45px 15px 45px;
 position: relative;
 width: 890px;
 margin: 0;
}

#page .section-list {
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 0;
}

#page .section-list li {
 clear: both;
 padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

#page ul {
 list-style: none;
}

#page ul li {
 border-top: solid 1px #D4D4D4;
 padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

#page ul li.first {
 padding-top: 0;
 border-top: 0;
}

#page-bottom {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 background: #000000 url('../images/banner2.jpg') no-repeat left top;
 width: 890px;
 height: 200px;
 padding: 45px 45px 0 45px;
 color: #000000;
}

#page-bottom a {
 color: #F5F5F5;
}

#page-bottom h2, #page-bottom h3, #page-bottom h4 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

#page-bottom ul {
 list-style: none;
}

#page-bottom ul li {
 border-top: solid 1px #8F8F8F;
 padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

#page-bottom ul li.first {
 padding-top: 0;
 border-top: 0;
}

#page-bottom-content {
 width: 665px;
 float: left;
 clear: right;
}

#page-bottom-sidebar {
 width: 200px;
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 float: right;
}

#search input.form-submit {
 margin-left: 1em;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #2FACAC;
 border: 0;
}

#search input.form-text {
 border: solid 1px #8F8F8F;
 padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 0 0 690px;
}

#splash {
 background: url('../images/lgcont.jpg');
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 height: 374px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 45px 45px 10px 45px;
 width: 890px;
}

#splash .pic {
 padding: 9px;
}

#wrapper {
 background: url('../images/lgcont.jpg');
    border: solid 1px #000000;
 background-size:cover;
 position: relative;
 width: 980px;
 margin: 75px auto 0 auto;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Mimars Energy Sdn Berhad - Your Best Partner in Business</title>
<link rel="icon" href="images/favImage.png" type="image/png"/>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<style type="text/css">
.style6 {
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.style7 {
 text-align: center;
}
.style8 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: xx-large;
}
.style9 {
 text-align: left;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.style10 {
 text-align: left;
}
.style13 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size: xx-large;
}
.style15 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size: x-large;
}
.style17 {
 font-size: large;
}
.style18 {
 text-align: left;
 font-size: large;
}
.style19 {
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size: large;
}
.style20 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: large;
}
.style21 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size: large;
}
.style22 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: small;
}
.style23 {
 font-size: x-large;
}
</style>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */

function myFunction(target) {  
    var dropdown = document.getElementById(target);
    var isOpen =  dropdown.classList.contains('show')
    closeAll();   
    if(!isOpen)
      dropdown.classList.toggle("show");
}
  
function closeAll() {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
 }

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
     closeAll();
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header" style="background-image: url('images/logo.jpg'); width: 890px">
  <img height="128" src="images/logo%20spin.gif" style="position: relative; left: 12px; top: -37px;" width="128" /></div>
 <div id="menu">
  <ul>
   <li class="first current_page_item"><span class="style6"><a href="index.html">
   Home</a></li>
   
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction('myDropdown1')">Profile</a>
       <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown1">
         <a href="profile.html">Mission & Vision</a>
         <a href="license.html">License</a>
       </div>
     </li> 
         
     <li><a href="project.html">Project</a></li>
   <li><a href="suppliers.html">Suppliers</a></li>
   
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction('myDropdown2')">Partners</a>
       <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown2">
         <a href="internationalpartners.html">International</a>
         <a href="localpartners.html">Local</a>
       </div>
     </li> 
       
     <li class="last"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br class="clearfix" />
 </div>
 <div id="page" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 1549px;">
  <table style="width: 100%">
   <tr>
    <td class="style13">
    <strong>WELCOME TO MIMARS ENERGY</strong></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
  <span class="style6"><br />
  <table style="width: 100%">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="style7" style="height: 269px"><span class="style6">
  
  <iframe src="slideshow.html" frameborder="0" style="border: thin solid #000000; width: 80%; height: 354px; left: 2px; top: -2px; overflow: hidden;" allowfullscreen id="I1" class="style8" name="I1"></iframe>
    </span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="style13" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="style21" colspan="4">We envision ourselves to become 
    the key provider of ICT solutions, manpower supply &amp; other 
    supplies and services to organizations locally and beyond.</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="style15" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="style15" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><span class="style13"><strong><br />
    <span class="style23">Services</span><br />
    </strong></span>
    <br class="style7" />
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px" class="style7"><span class="style6"></span>
    <img alt="network" height="103" src="images/network.png" style="position: relative; left: 12px; top: -3px;" width="102" /></td>
    <td style="width: 4584px" class="style10"><span class="style17">Network</span><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </strong></td>
    <td style="width: 4035px" class="style7"><span class="style6"></span>
    <img alt="manpower" height="107" src="images/manpower.png" style="position: relative; left: 22px; top: 1px;" width="105" /></td>
    <td style="width: 4634px" class="style17">Manpower</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px">
    <img alt="software" height="105" src="images/software.png" style="position: relative; left: 66px; top: 2px;" width="103" /><br class="style7" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 4584px" class="style18">Software</td>
    <td style="width: 4035px" class="style7"><span class="style6"></span>
    <img alt="safety" height="107" src="images/safety.png" style="position: relative; left: 24px; top: -2px;" width="104" /></td>
    <td style="width: 4634px" class="style17">Safety</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px">
    <img alt="videoconference" height="101" src="images/video.png" style="position: relative; left: 67px; top: 3px;" width="102" /></td>
    <td style="width: 4584px" class="style10"><span class="style17">Video Conferencing &amp; 
    AV/</span><span class="style19">Solutions</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><span class="style6"><strong>
    <span class="style13"><br />
        <span class="style23">News &amp; Events</span><br />
    </span>
    </strong></span>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px">
    <img alt="computer" height="83" src="images/Computer.png" style="position: relative; left: 79px; top: 3px;" width="83" /></td>
    <td class="style9" colspan="3"><span class="style20">Supply &amp; 
    Maintenance Computers for </span><strong><span class="style20">JX 
    Nippon Oil &amp; Energy Corporation (Miri Branch)</span></strong></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px">
    <img height="56" src="images/flircam.jpg" style="position: relative; left: 83px; top: 1px;" width="83" /></td>
    <td colspan="3"><span class="style7"><span class="style17">Installing 
    FLIR camera at </span> 
    </span> <span class="style20"> <strong>PETRONAS Miri Crude Oil Terminal </strong></span>
    <span class="style22">(Click <a href="project3page.html">here</a> to view)</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 3889px">
    <img height="83" src="images/cardaccess.png" style="position: relative; left: 82px; top: 0px;" width="83" /></td>
    <td colspan="3"><span class="style20">Security Access Management System at </span> 
    <span class="style20"> <strong>
    PETRONAS 
    FLNG Building </strong></span>
    <span class="style22">(Click <a href="project2page.html">here</a> to view)</span></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <span class="style6"></span>
 </div>
 <div id="page-bottom" style="left: 0px; top: 0px">
 </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 Copyright &copy; 2016 <a href="index.html">www.mimars.com.my</a> All rights reserved.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx, you too. Maybe you should close the question ;)